# Application-scope variables in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Is there such thing as application-scope python variables in Flask? I'd like to implement some primitive messaging between users, and shared data cache. Of course, it is possible to implement this via a database, but I wanted to know maybe there is a db-free and perhaps faster approach. Ideally, if the shared variable would be a live python object, but my needs would be satisfied with strings and ints, too.

Edit: complemented with (non-working) example

```
from flask import g

@app.route('/store/<name>')
def view_hello(name=None):
    g.name = name
    return "Storing " + g.name

@app.route("/retrieve")
def view_listen():
    n = g.name
    return "Retrieved: " + n
```

At trying to retrieve g.name, this triggers error:
AttributeError: '_RequestGlobals' object has no attribute 'name'

Answer (score 4):

I'm unsure whether this is a good idea or not, but I've been using this to share data easily between requests:

```
class MyServer(Flask):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(MyServer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

            #instanciate your variables here
            self.messages = []

app = MyServer(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def foo():
    app.messages.append("message")
```

Comment: This approach assumes that it is the same app object that is shared between the requests and that it never dies. I am pretty sure that does not hold in more complex scenarios than the simple dev webserver that is built within the Flask framework.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For very small and simple applications it is an easy way of sharing the data, though.

Answer (score -8):

Since flask 0.10 `flask.g` would be the way to go.

In earlier versions flask.g is stored in the request context and is cleared between requests. If you're using an older version you should store your app level stuff in `flask.current_app`

Comment: The document says `flask.g` is a special object that ensures it is only valid for the active request and that will return different values for each request. Clearly it is not the right answer to this question.